# Schedule Training and Testing Script in Python

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I have this simple RandomForest Regression Model which does training and testing and then prints the predictions and model accuracy. I want to write a python automated script for scheduling this code which will do training once every month and testing once every week automatically.

Model Code:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
from main import data as df


class Model():
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = df
        self.linear_reg = LinearRegression()
        self.random_forest = RandomForestRegressor()
    def split(self, test_size):
        X = np.array(self.df[['age','experience','education','certificates']])
        y = np.array(self.df['salary'])
        self.X_train, self.X_test, self.y_train, self.y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = test_size, random_state = 42)

    def fit(self):
        self.model = self.random_forest.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)

    def predict(self):

        self.result = self.random_forest.predict(self.X_test)
        return self.result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model_instance = Model()
    model_instance.split(0.2)
    model_instance.fit()
    model_instance.predict()
    print(model_instance.result)
    print("Accuracy: ", model_instance.model.score(model_instance.X_test, model_instance.y_test))
```

This is the training part I want to schedule for once every month

```
    def fit(self):
        self.model = self.random_forest.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)
```

And this is the testing part I want to schedule for once every week

```
     def predict(self):

        self.result = self.random_forest.predict(self.X_test)
        return self.result
```

**How can I write code that schedules the training and testing in the described time frames?**

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to write a python script for scheduling the training and testing automatically every month and every week respectfully.

Comment: What Brian asks is: Do you want help with the scheduling or the training + testing? What is your actual problem that you want to have addressed? Nevertheless, what is the purpose of your post? If you train once a month the test results every 3 weeks will  stay the same.

Comment: @LeonidGlanz yes I want help with scheduling training+testing. The testing data will keep on changing every week. Please could you help.

Comment: I have added an answer that uses the module schedule to perform the desired task.

Comment: if you are running this locally, you can write a system cron job. if this is on server, you could use some job management platform which are usually backed by in-memory databases like redis.

Comment: @LeonidGlanz on this particular line of code `schedule.every(28).days.at("07:00").do(model_instance.fit())` 
I'm getting an error
 `the first argument must be callable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution could be achieved using [schedule](https://pypi.org/project/schedule/):

```
import schedule
import time
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd
from main import data as df

class Model():
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = df
        self.linear_reg = LinearRegression()
        self.random_forest = RandomForestRegressor()
    def split(self, test_size):
        X = np.array(self.df[['age','experience','education','certificates']])
        y = np.array(self.df['salary'])
        self.X_train, self.X_test, self.y_train, self.y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = test_size, random_state = 42)

    def fit(self):
        self.model = self.random_forest.fit(self.X_train, self.y_train)

    def predict(self):

        self.result = self.random_forest.predict(self.X_test)
        print(self.result)
        print("Accuracy: ", self.model.score(self.X_test, self.y_test))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    model_instance = Model()
    model_instance.split(0.2)
    schedule.every(28).day.at("07:00").do(model_instance.fit())
    schedule.every(7).day.at("07:00").do(model_instance.predict())
    while 1:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Also how can I automate this on cloud?

Comment: Automation on a cloud depends on the cloud provider but this would be another question.